# postgreSQL collation problem when comparing a column value with a given value

Tags: postgresql, collation

Assume that we created a table and inserted a record with the following script.

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( your_column VARCHAR COLLATE "tr-TR-x-icu" );
INSERT INTO your_table(your_column) VALUES ('Gider');
```

When I executed the following revised script I got the 'not equal' as a result. The result should be 'equal' since I use "tr-TR-x-icu" collation of the column and the upper of the text 'Gider' is 'GİDER' in Turkish.

```sql
SELECT 
CASE WHEN UPPER(your_column)=UPPER('Gider') THEN 'equal' 
     ELSE 'not equal' 
END AS result 
FROM your_table;
```

When I executed the following script I got the correct answer (i.e. 'equal').

```sql
SELECT 
CASE WHEN UPPER(your_column)=UPPER('Gider' COLLATE "tr-TR-x-icu") THEN 'equal' 
     ELSE 'not equal' 
END AS result 
FROM your_table;
```

It would be nice if there is method of setting this collate property inside this session.

For example, adding like `SET COLLATE...` right before the query.

In this way, instead of writing `UPPER(your_column)=UPPER('Gider' COLLATE "tr-TR-x-icu")`, it would be sufficient to just write `UPPER(your_column)=UPPER('Gider')`.

I would be happy if anyone could offer a solution.
Best wishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the default collation to be `tr-TR-x-icu`, create your database with the appropriate ICU collation (from v15 on):

```
CREATE DATABASE turkish
   TEMPLATE template0
   LOCALE_PROVIDER icu
   ICU_LOCALE "tr-TR"
   LOCALE "tr_TR.utf8";
```

Then connect to the database, and it will behave like you want:

```
SELECT upper('Gider'), lower('KADIN');

 upper │ lower 
═══════╪═══════
 GİDER │ kadın
(1 row)
```

Comment: Your suggestion works very well, Laurenz. Thanks.